# SVG 1.2 rasterizing via ImageMagick: vector-effect issue

Tags: svg, imagemagick, ubuntu-server, ubuntu-22.04

I've noticed different behavior of ImageMagick CLI utility `convert` of the same version, but on different versions of Ubuntu 22.04: desktop and docker container.

I want to render SVG utilizing SVG 1.2 attribute vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke":

```xml
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    width="200"
    height="200"
>
    <g
        x="0"
        y="0"
        transform="scale(4)"
    >
        <rect
            x="25"
            y="25"
            width="50"
            height="50"
            fill="#0cc"
            stroke="black"
            stroke-width="2"
            vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"
        ></rect>
    </g>
</svg>
```

I run next command within bash both on Xubuntu Desktop 22.04 and Ubuntu 22.04 server:

```bash
convert test.svg test.png
```

and I get expected result on Xubuntu 22.04 Desktop:

[Desktop output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BagXb.png) - there are thin, non-scaled stroke and also transparent background.

But I get lack of `vector-effect` applying on Ubuntu 22.04 server within Docker container:

[Server output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/88RjJ.png) - there are thick scaled stroke and force filled background.

Both system have the same ImageMagick version:

```bash
convert --version
Version: ImageMagick 6.9.11-60 Q16 x86_64 2021-01-25
```

I need to force server version of ImageMagick to take vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" into account.

Comment: You get only SVG 1.2 features, if use _inkscape_ as backend to render SVG > PNG. Hence you could escape _imagemagick_ and use directly _inkscape_ CLI to render your SVG.

Comment: You can probably find which SVG renderer **ImageMagick** is using with `magick -debug all  image.svg a.png 2>&1 | grep -Ei "inkscape|svg" `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is likely which SVG renderer you are using on your two Imagemagick systems. It could be Imagemagick's internal MSVG/XML renderer, RSVG delegate or Inkscape if Inkscape is installed on the system (where IM can find it) all in order of increasing quality of the render. Check which is being used possibly by add -verbose to your command line.

Comment: Thnx a lot! I tried to run convert verbously, but it gives no info about renderer. Then I tried to install inkscape inside container and run `convert` after that. Having installed inkscape, I get expected result out `convert` - SVG 1.2 features like `vector-effect='non-scaling-stroke'` and transparent background are both in place.

Comment: Do you know if `convert` has an argument for `render` assigning? I could see only `-render` argument as command.

Comment: Sorry, I do not know what "render assigning" means.  Can you clarify what that does? If you mean which SVG renderer is used, that is determined by what you install.  If you install nothing, IM MSVG/XML is used. If you install RSVG delegate when installing IM, you get RSVG. If you install Inkscape on your system, you get Inkscape in place of either RSVG or MSVG.  The use of -verbose tells you which, but is hard to understand. convert -list format often identifies either MSVG/XML or RSVG but does not show Inkscape. You can switch by creating and calling special entries in the delegates.xml file